# Website display an error SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' in IE 11

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I used vue js 2 in one of website, and it turned out that there were some compatibility issue in earlier releases of internet explorer.

The error is

```
SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
```

Here is the code

```
methods: {
          dataLoaded() {
            var ctx = this;
            if (window.location.hash) {
              var fragmentData = window.location.hash
                .replace("#", ""),
                .split("/");
              var categoryId = fragmentData[0];
              var categoryIndex = null;
              var offerIndex = parseInt(fragmentData[1]);
              var category = this.categories.filter(function(category, index) {
                if (category.id == categoryId) categoryIndex = index;
                return category.id == categoryId;
              })[0];
              if (category) {
                if (!category.loaded) {
                  this.loadOffers(category, function() {
                    if (category.offers[offerIndex]) {
                      ctx.showDetails(
                        category.offers[offerIndex],
                        categoryIndex,
                        offerIndex
                      );
                    }
                  });
                } else if (category.offers[offerIndex]) {
                  this.showDetails(
                    category.offers[offerIndex],
                    categoryIndex,
                    offerIndex
                  );
                }
              }
            }
          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 doesn’t support the [method definition shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) 495. You either need to use babel as a transpiler or change your dataloaded hook to `dataLoaded(): function() { //... }`

Comment: I added the suggested changes. Now it display other error as "[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: 'Promise' is undefined"

Comment: Sounds like you need to polyfill Promise’s for IE11. npm install --save babel-polyfill and change webpack config

Comment: what is the error? try npm i es6-promise instead a babel-polyfil

Comment: and import 'es6-promise/auto' in main.js

Comment: It display an error "[object Error]{description: "'Promise' i...", message: "'Promise' i...", name: "ReferenceEr...", number: -2146823279, stack: "ReferenceEr..."}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184304/discussion-between-alex-malikov-and-user2893).